# octave errors for columns that don't exist

Tags: matlab, error-handling, octave

I am trying to run the following script in octave:

I write this script in notepad and save it as rectsin.m

```
t = linspace(0, 10, 100);
y = abs(sin(t));
plot(t,y);
title('Rectified Sine Wave');
xlabel('t');
```

I then try to call it in octave using the command

```
rectsin
```

but I get the following error:

```
'rectsin' undefined near line 9 column 1
```

now sure what to do here, any  ideas as to what causes this ?

Comment: Is `rectsin.m` in your working directory?

Comment: how do i set the working directory?

Comment: sorry, new to programming..

Comment: use command 'cd' to go to the directory where your file is.

Comment: it returns that there is no such file or directory. How do i set a working directory?

Comment: "pwd" shows the current working directory. "ls" lists the files in your workind directory, this should list your rectsin.m, otherwise you have to change it with "cd". Use "cd .." to go one step up, "cd yourfolder" to change the current working directory to yourfolder.

Comment: As @Andy says, is `rectsin.m` in your current directory (the one returned by `pwd`)?

Comment: thanks for your help, i saved it in my working directory, although i was still getting errors until i changed the quotations in title and xlabel to double quotations..didn't think that would matter. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have a function called `labelx('t');`. I think it should be `xlabel('t');`

Comment: sorry it was an exercise question i copied from the book, I fixed it up in my actual code and was still getting the error